# Android Studio design tab blank except for white dot in top left, won't work, but when running app works fine

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[What my screen shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pJ4g.png)

That little white dot that I circled is the textview (I have to zoom in to 1000% just to click it accurately). This is what my android studio shows on the preview screen when I load up the default "empty activity". I can drag other objects in but they just disappear. The Design view shows the app view but empty. When I actually run the app it appears normal, but it makes it really difficult to make the app without use of this feature. I've tried like 5 new projects but it's all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i experience this problem too, try this answer :

[My design view on Android Studio is blank. It doesn't change. I have tried syncing with gradle build too. What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829609/my-design-view-on-android-studio-is-blank-it-doesnt-change-i-have-tried-synci)

it works for me after downgrading the appcompat to alpha1

Answer (score 0):

[image: On the Select Design Surface option, Click Force Refresh Layout]

On the Select Design Surface option, Click Force Refresh Layout. That should work.

Edit: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707341/android-studio-3-1-layout-preview-does-not-show-preview-for-some-layouts)

Edit 2:

> In the Project View, try deleting the ".idea" folder. Then, Change a
>   small thing in any "build.gradle" file, and it will give you the
>   option to "Sync project". Try this.
>
> If not, try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and
>   Restart

Comment: Updated answer with next steps.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm going to try to completely uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling.