# My design view on Android Studio is blank. It doesn't change. I have tried syncing with gradle build too. What to do?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="34dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout
```

Need help asap.What to do??

Comment: showing error at top-right corner check it...

Comment: try clean,rebuild. If not try closing the android studio then reopen it again. If those two ain't working try clicking invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: I fixed this by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611939/28558).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem yesterday after updating android studio,
Go to Gradle Scripts -> Build.Gradle(Module:app)

[image: Gradle]

change alpha3 to alpha1

```
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

[image]

Note: [Edit] This solution doesn't work anymore as version codes have been updated, stable version has been released

Comment: Is there a way to report this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Just building the project: Build -> Make Project

If that doesn't work try cleaning the project: Build -> Rebuild and Clean Project

That happened to me as well and all I had to do was build the project. Then it was able to render it.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code, it's working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```