# Layout preview not rendering - possibly due to androidx.widget

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, kotlin

The layout preview in Android Studio isn't rendering and I am unsure why. I have everything updated to the latest version, and it seems to run fine on other computers. My professor wasn't sure how to fix this and all the other layout rendering Stack Overflow posts I could find are outdated. I've tried refreshing it, restarting it, rebuilding it, invalidating caches, etc...

The best clue I could get is that it has to due with the androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout not being properly supported. My professor also mentioned that there might be an issue with Jetpack? Not quite sure what he means.

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/totalTwentyEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/totalFifteenEditText" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" android:text="0.00" android:textAlignment="center"
            android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline2" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="86dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline3" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="128dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline4"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="191dp"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline5" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="259dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline6" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="309dp"
                                                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/leftColumn"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView3,textView5,textView4,textView2,textView"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/bill_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/billTotalEditText"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textAlignment="viewEnd" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/leftColumn"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tipTenEditText"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textAlignment="viewEnd" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/leftColumn"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/totalTenEditText"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/custom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textAlignment="viewEnd" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/leftColumn"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/customSeekBar"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textAlignment="viewEnd" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/leftColumn"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tipEditText"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="302dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/billTotalEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftColumn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/tipTenEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tipFifteenEditText" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/tipFifteenEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tipTenEditText" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tipTwentyEditText" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/tipTwentyEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tipFifteenEditText" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/tenPercent"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView6" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tipTenEditText" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tipTenEditText"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/fifteenPercent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tipFifteenEditText" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tipFifteenEditText"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/twentyPercent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView8" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tipTwentyEditText" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tipTwentyEditText"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/totalTenEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/totalFifteenEditText" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/totalFifteenEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/totalTenEditText" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/totalTwentyEditText" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/customSeekBar" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/customTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftColumn"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:progress="18" android:max="100"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/eighteenPercent"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:id="@+id/customTextView" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/totalTwentyEditText" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/totalTwentyEditText"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/customSeekBar"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/tipEditText" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/totalTenEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/totalTenEditText"
            android:text="@string/zeroDecimal" android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false"
            android:longClickable="false"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView10" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textAlignment="viewEnd" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tipEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/totalFifteenEditText" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/totalFifteenEditText"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/totalEditText" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/totalTwentyEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/totalTwentyEditText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" android:text="@string/zeroDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center" android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tipcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ["Force Refresh Layout"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49791978/115145) worked for me when I ran into this problem yesterday. While the linked-to answer is for Android Studio 3.1, it worked for me on 3.3.1.

Comment: @CommonsWare I wish - I've tried it, and I can tell it refreshes but the layout doesn't change

Comment: Press the red explanation mark and show us the error.Did you clean your build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see your implementations are wrong:

```
com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
```

You should have:

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3
```

And also a few others like:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
```

To fix all goto Refactor(menu)->migrateToAndroidX
if you don't have such an option update your ide(Android Studio).

Comment: Hey - you were definitely right but now I get an error that says v7 in import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity is an unresolved reference in my main activity.

Comment: Nevermind I removed that part - it works now. I would also like to mention that the rendering didn't work until I put android.enableJetifier=true in the gradle properties

Comment: @Mia Yes the refactor is a big buggy you should just fix some parts your self just remove the red import statements and add new import statements by alt + enter.android.enableJetifier=true is supposed to be added by refactor. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can go to Refractor Menu and then -> Click on Migrate To Android
   X
2. These dependencies will be added automatically, if not you can add these (Note: Dependency Versions may vary)

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'

   implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'

   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
   ```
3. Try "Force Refresh Layout" option from Layout Editor in preview.
4. If the 3rd Option doesn't help, try cleaning and rebuilding your project. This should fix the issue.

I know this question has already an answer but these steps might help someone as i fixed the same problem using these steps.